# Why assigning a value to date type object is not getting it's value properly?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, date, datetime

I have a winforms datetime pickers which has custom format as

```
txtEndDateTextBox.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        txtEndDateTextBox.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

but when I assign it to

```
 n.N_DATE = txtEndDateTextBox.Value
```

it is getting assigned as `#11/7/2019 12:41:02 AM#`

`The data type of N_DATE is`Date`.

Same goes for the other i.e.

```
        NTime.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        NTime.CustomFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
```

when assigned to `n.NTime` of type date it has value `#1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM#`

Comment: The `Value` is always `DateTime`, format just determines the string representation of the value.

Comment: ok but there must be some way of removing it because the webservice expects only date

Comment: Yes, there is. The easiest is using [`Text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.text?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8)  property of `DateTimePicker`.

Comment: I checked, there's no Text property for DateTimePicker in winforms

Comment: There is [`Text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.text?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property, but it's not browsable at design-time. Use it in code.

Comment: wait let me try

Comment: I did but still it is #11/7/2019 12:00:00 AM# after getting assigned.

Comment: You are assigning a DateTime variable, it stores Date *and* Time.  The `Date` type in vb.net is legacy, it is still a DateTime.  Truncate the value you get from DTP by using Value.Date, it turns the time to midnight.  It isn't obvious what kind of value you need to produce, smells like it is a string.  use DateTime.ToString(), passing the format specifier you need.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property of `DateTimePicker` is always `DateTime`. The format just specifies the string representation of the value.

If you want to get the string representation of the value in the specified format, you can easily use the [`Text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.text?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property.

As another option, you can always call `ToString` method of `DateTime` and pass [custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

**Example - 1**

```
DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
'...
'Then to get text:
Dim DateText As String = DateTimePicker1.Text
```

**Example - 2**

```
Dim DateText As String = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: I did but still it is #11/7/2019 12:00:00 AM# after getting assigned.

Comment: Pay attention to the type of property. If you assign something to a `DateTime` type, it will be always date time. If you assign it to a `String` it will be string.

Comment: the type is date actually. And if the webservice is expecting date in specific format then if I pass wrong format it will fail

Comment: If the web service expects the string representation, then the post answers your question. If the web service expects `DateTime` type, then the format doesn't makes sense for `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you put a value in a TextBox.Text property it becomes a String. Don't pass the value through a TextBox. If n.N_Date is expecting a date you must pass it a date not a string.

```
n.N_DATE = DateTimePicker1.Value
```

Or, if you need only the date component.

```
n.N_Date = DataTimePicker1.Value.Date
```

If you must use the TextBox

```
n.N_Date = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox1.Text, "mm/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Replace whatever your actual format is for "mm/dd/yyyy".